# question about the conditional pdf

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

$X_1,X_2$ are two r.v.
when $f_{X_1}(x_1)>0$,define the conditional pdf
$$f_{X_2|X_1}(x_2|x_1)=\frac{f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)}{f_{X_1}(x_1)}$$
then
$$\mathbb P(A|X_1=x_1)=\int_Af_{X_2|X_1}(x_2|x_1)\,dx_2$$
is a probability measure

then we can define
$$\mathbb E\left[u(X_2)|x_1\right]=\int_\mathbb{R}u(x_2)f_{X_2|X_1}(x_2|x_1)\,dx_2=g(x_1)$$

at last we can conclude that $\mathbb E\left[u(X_2)|X_1\right]=g(X_1)$

My question is how to get
$$\mathbb E\left[u(X_2)|X_2\right]=u(X_2)$$
using the reason above?

I found it hard to determine $f_{X_2,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: Such hope is doomed from the start since one assumes that $(X_1,X_2)$ has a density. If $X_2=X_1$, the support of the distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ is (a subset of) the diagonal hence it has no density. This is one reason why conditional expectations are best defined **not** using densities.